# ALT+Tab window order Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, games

For some reason, full screen applications (games really) are being put last every time I alt tab out. If I alt+tab out of a game then try to alt tab back in the game will be put last in rotation behind Discord/Steam/Firefox/Chrome and I have to shift+alt+tab to get immediately back in where as with every other window like between Discord/Firefox I can just spam alt+tab and jump between those windows without having to shift+alt+tab. Was this intentional? Can I change this behavior?